# App for setting up 2FA for the same account on different mobile phones?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

At work I manage several online accounts together with my colleague. 2FA set up on a mobile is useful as security but causes issues for us because we cannot access the same accounts without 'helping' each other with a code - we work in different cities. Is there an app that would allow installing the Google 2FA on both our mobiles for the same accounts? 
Is that even technically possible?

Answer (score 2):

Google's "mobile authenticator" 2FA is ordinary OATH-TOTP and is tied only to the master key which you scan from the QR code. There is no limit to how many devices can do this – you can just scan the same QR from both, or even write down the alphanumeric master key itself.

Google's "verification prompt" 2FA is tied to the phone, but it is allowed to [add multiple phones](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7026266?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

Comment: There are Windows desktop programs that allow you to have a Google authenticator on your desktop.  You can put unlimited Google authenticators all on the same device.